# QuickText in notepad++ not saving code snippets!

Tags: notepad++

I installed notepad++ 5.8.5 on Windows7. Now I'm trying to configure quicktext with notepad++ but it is not working. It saves the snippets and I can use them, but when I restart the notepad++, all snipets are gone. They are not persisting or sticking.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Question is a little old, but I had the same problem and found a solution:

The target directory for the file `QuickText.ini` is `Notepad++\plugins\Config\` as you can see in the changelog. The `ReadMe` file hasn't been updated for this change, so the installation "fails".

I put `QuickText.ini` in the correct directory and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try Fingertext. It's a snippet plugin that can be downloaded from Notepad++ plugin manager or here http://sourceforge.net/projects/fingertext/

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like QuickText plugin does not supported more. Try snippets

Comment: can you provide any link please? Is snippets a plugin?

Comment: I would +1 this answer if it had a link to this magic "snippets" you speak of. On the other hand, it doesn't really answer the question which was why the snippets in QuickText are not saving.